# How to execute a page's function from firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a website that I want to automatically navigate through, so I decided to see if I can write a firefox add-on.

I have the following code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "Demonstrating toolbar buttons",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "button-demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_page.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/page-16.png",
      "32": "icons/page-32.png"
    }
  }
}
```

choose_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="choose_page.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-choice">developer.mozilla.org</div>
    <div class="page-choice">support.mozilla.org</div>
    <div class="page-choice">addons.mozilla.org</div>
    <script src="choose_page.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

choose_page.js

```
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("page-choice")) {
    return;
  }


  browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(tabs => {
    let activeTab = tabs[0];
    console.log('activeTab: ', activeTab)
    console.log('activeTab id: ', activeTab.id)
    let activeTabUrl = activeTab.url;
    console.log("Active tab URL:", activeTabUrl);

    browser.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
      code: 'top[3].function1()'
    }, (results) => {
      if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(browser.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        console.log('success: ', results);
      }
    });

  }).catch(error => {
    console.error("Error getting active tab URL:", error);
  });
});
```

I got the script from firefox tutorial. Basically, I click the extension which will bring up a popup, then I click a button.

However, I'm getting undefined behavior.

Is it possible to execute a page's function?

Thanks

I tried the code that I wrote